Croatian Visa was refused, can I still apply to the same country
I was refused a Croatian tourist visa due to 'justification on the purpose and conditions of intended stay was not stated'.
Can I still apply the same country within the 30 days?
Thank you
Selassie

You can, but unless you improve your application to address the refusal reason you’ll just get another refusal.

Probably they are trying to show before their Schengen join, that they are very secure. Things will likely improve after that, although it helps you only a little now, unfortunately.
